# Two different multiplications of the equations does not give the same answer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The product of $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$ is $y^2=x^5$.

By manipulating the equations to $0=x^2-y$ and $0=x^3-y$ first their product is $0=(x^2-y)(x^3-y)$ or $0=y^2-yx^2-yx^3+x^5$.

Please explain why their roots are different!!!

Comment: you are confusing equations with functions

Comment: I don't understand your concerns.  $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$ together imply that $y^2=x^5$.  This is true.  If you have a solution set of the initial equations, these solutions will necessarily be solutions of the later equation as well (*but might not comprise all of the solutions of the later equation, you may have unnecessarily introduced more*).  On the other hand, $y^2=x^5$ does not imply that $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$.  Similarly, your hypothesis will imply your second longer equation, but again your second longer equation does not imply your hypotheses and may admit additional solutions.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between bi-implications ($\iff$) and forward only implications ($\implies$).  If you use forward only implications which are not bi-implications, new solutions can be added.  For instance, if $x=y$ we can know that $x^2=y^2$ follows, but $x^2=y^2$ has as solutions not only the solutions of $x=y$ but also the solutions of $x=-y$.

Comment: If you "multiply" $x=2$ and $x=3$, you get $x^2=6$, but what relation does that "product" have to the original equations? None at all, because you haven't really made a product, you've made a nonsense.

Comment: Here's another angle. $y=x^2$ is the same thing as $x^2=y$. So "multiplying" $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$ is the same as multiplying $x^2=y$ and $y=x^3$, which gives you $x^2y=x^3y$, which gives you $y=0$ or $x=0$ or $x=1$, which tells you how sensible it was to do the "multiplication" in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is the *meaning* of the equals sign “$=$”. It means “is”. It means that the expressions on the left and right of the equals sign are descriptions of the same one number, signify the same one number.

You want to write $y=x^2$ and you want to use another equation $y=x^3$. If both instances of the $y$ and the $x$ refer to the same number, then it makes sense to “multiply” the two equations, even though there might be little reason to do so. If the two $x$’s, call them $x_1$ and $x_2$, are not the same, then you’d have to keep the subscripts when multiplying.

But when you take the two equations together, I look at them and say that if we’re accepting both as describing the same $x$ and the same $y$, then certainly $x^2=x^3$, true only of $x=0$ and $x=1$.